# How to recovery to different environment using Cassy backup tool?

Tags: scalardb, cassy

I want to know how to recover Scalar DB to another instance using Cassy backup.
Because I need a new instance for tests from the production environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct support in Cassy to load backups that were taken in a cluster to another cluster.
Since Cassy only manages snapshots of Cassandra, you can follow [the doc](https://docs.datastax.com/en/ddac/doc/datastax_enterprise/operations/opsSnapshotRestoreNewCluster.html) to do it.

For testing, I would recommend dumping some of the data from the current (possibly production) cluster and load it to a new testing cluster.